# How to scale Image Views without any code?

Tags: android, imageview

I have some big picture and I want to put it to the one of the activities. How can I simply resize it without any code, e.g. using only Eclipse with ADT? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to scale it in your layout. If so, you can use `ScaleType` in XML. Just use the `android:scaleType` tag. More info available here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to scale it manually, something like free transform tool in Photoshop?

Comment: I really can't see why you'd want to use Eclipse for that. Just use Photoshop then or something similar. This is not programming related then.